MediaPipe Landmarks but for skeleton hand
I need to estimate the 3d bounding box of a 3d-printed skeletton hand, to overlay an AR 3d-model after that.
How could i trick the model to recognize my skeletton hand? Is there a more simple alternative?
I have invested hours of research and the closest I've seen by now is the mediapipe landmarks from google. However, it doesnt recognize the skeletton hand. I tried to play around with different colors for the 3d-printed hand but it had no effect. Only a glove over the skeletton hand was recognized once, which is not an alternative.
